# How to solve Error -32000 received from application: Service protocol could not handle or find a handler for the requested method. error

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to implement google sign-in feature in firebase into my flutter (android) app.
The sign-in works perfectly, but once I click hot restart after signing in the app I get the following error:

> Error -32000 received from application: Service protocol could not handle or find a handler for the requested method.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This Error maybe due to an old [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) plugin. You can update to the latest plugin or try running `flutter clean`

Comment: well, I have updated the google_sign_in plugin as you said and it worked. thank you

Comment: Always try to Update the google_sign_in plugin when it's outdated it may cause problems